# Geometric Definitions: What is a straight line? What is a circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, definition, circles

What is a straight line? I need a geometric definition of it. The equation of a straight line is known to me. I am saying about a straight line of $2$D plane.

What is a circle? I need a geometric definition of it. The equation of a circle is known to me.

I know there is an algebraic side and a geometric side in $2$D geometry.
I needed geometric explanation. And, I thought points make a straight line. Is it fine to think like that?

Comment: To go along with amWhy's nice response, you can also read [*Line (geometry)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) for a historical perspective. Regards

Comment: "The locus of points satisfying an 'equation of a straight line'" is a perfectly good definition of "straight line".

Comment: I needed geometric explanation.And, I thought points make a straight line.Is it fine to think like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A straight line is the path of shortest distance between two points, though "line" and "point" are typically considered to be "primitives," axiomatically.

A circle is the set of all points equidistant from a given point (the given point being the center of the resultant circle).

Comment: Those are not equations, they are Euclidean geometric definitions.

Comment: @ReekMaths: There's not a single equation in the above answer...

Comment: "... and extending through them" is a bit unclear. There doesn't seem to be anything in that wording that prevents the behaviour outside of the line segment joining the two points being "wild".

Comment: Nope, those are the bases of equations.After getting the solution sets for a line and a circle, what we have, are a circle and a line. Now, what do we see on the Euclidean plane? I want to know this.

Comment: This answer is valid only when the space is endowed with a (Riemannian) metric.

Comment: These are definitions that need only a straightedge and compass to construct: what you see is what you get.

Comment: @Andrea I am answering in the context of Euclidean Geometry (as indicated by the given tag). It's as valid as is Euclidean Geometry. I'm not advocating its merits, only constraining myself within that context.

Comment: Say something regarding points.

Comment: Points are taken as given in Euclidean Geometry: "undefinable", objects with no measure, no area. I'm just trying to help, ReekMaths. I'm not going to get into an argument with you. Why would I take time to answer your post if I wasn't trying to be helpful?

Comment: "A straight line is the path of shortest distance connecting two points." --here a line segment has been mentioned. amWhy, I know you are trying to know my question.

Comment: I haven't been told by the books that a point is undefined. Experts said me that a point is an idea.

Comment: @amWhy: you are right, but it would be nice to have an intrinsic geometric definition of a straight line that would apply to more general situation, e.g. lines in affine spaces.

Comment: @ReekMaths: points *are* undefined. If you wish you can consider just any nonempty set $S$, call *points* its elements and *lines* certain subsets of $S$ satisfying a certain list of properties.

Comment: Within the framework of Euclidean geometry, a circle is *by definition* what amWhy said, and as far as I know, straight lines are primitive notions like points are (in classical Euclidean geometry, that is... of course it can be redone with metrics and such).

Comment: yes, points are an idea.If it is undefined, then what is a point?

Comment: @Andrea Mori:Thank you.I need more clarifications, can you please clarify a bit more about those sets you were talking about.

Comment: There's an essay by Quine in which he points out that there are at least four different ways to define a line: It's the path of shortest distance between two points (which is the source of the word, which refers to s stretched thread); it's the path of light rays (which is related to it being the shortest distance); it's the crease you get when you fold a piece of paper (related to its being the intersection of two planes, not obviously related to the first two), and a fourth I unfortunately forget.

Comment: The fourth is that a line has constant curvature that is the same on both sides: "Constant curvature plus symmetry yield straightness of line. It would take quite a substantial chapter of geometry to show why the taut string, the crease, and the sliding card all attest to the same simple quality. The remaining criterion, the line of sight, we leave to the physicist." *Quiddities*.

Answer (score 0):

straight line
locus of a point without changing any direction is a straight line.

circle: locus of a point forming closed curve and maintain equal distance from a fixed point(the center)

Comment: The definition of line is not ok, mathematically speaking. The definition of circle is poorly phrased. Overall, it's just a confusing mixture of physical definition and basic geometrical properties.

Comment: The concept of "direction" is not clear from the point of a grumpy Greek geometer with a straightedge and a compass, so this is not a good definition of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Any bounded and connected two-dimensional shape with more than one points, all of which are indistinguishable from each-other is called a **circle**.

Any unbounded and connected one-dimensional shape with all its points being indistinguishable from each-other is a called **line**.

Answer (score 0):

A straight line is a line traced by a point in a constant direction
A locus of all the points traced which are at a constant distance r from a point c is called a circle with centre c and radius r